# GWT: How do I center content in a panel?

Tags: gwt

I'm using GWT 2.4.  I have a view with some simple content ...

```
    final Image ajaxImage = new Image("loading.gif");
    final Grid grid = new Grid(1, 2); 
    grid.setText(0, 0, "Loading...");
    grid.setWidget(0, 1, ajaxImage);
    this.container = new FlowPanel();
    this.container.add(grid);
    rootPanel = new SimplePanel();
    rootPanel.add(this.container);
```

I would like this content to be centered horizontally and vertically in the containing panel, which is a FlowPanel, if that matters.  How do I do that?

Thanks, - Dave

Answer (score 6):

I know how to do it in a verticalpanel.

```
VerticalPanel panelPrincipal3 = new VerticalPanel();//Esto es el panel central, donde se centra todo
    panelPrincipal3.setWidth("100%");
    panelPrincipal3.setHeight("100%");
    panelPrincipal3.setHorizontalAlignment(HasHorizontalAlignment.ALIGN_CENTER);
    panelPrincipal3.setVerticalAlignment(HasVerticalAlignment.ALIGN_MIDDLE);
    panelPrincipal3.add(/*your panel*/);//here yo add whatever yo want, and should be centered
```

Comment: Worked like a charm CSS is confusing on this issue. Thanks! is there a CSS parallel?

Comment: .setHeight("100%"); doesn't work anymore. Try .setHeight(Window.getClientHeight() + "px");

Answer (score 2):

if you were to put your `FlowPanel` as a direct child of your `RootPanel`, you can try to set its `height` to `100%`. so if you only have a grid as a child component for your container, you can set its alignments like this:

```
container.setCellHorizontalAlignment( grid, HasHorizontalAlignment.ALIGN_CENTER );
container.setCellVerticalAlignment( grid, HasVerticalAlignment.ALIGN_MIDDLE );
```

But if you ever change your mind and you'll switch to `UiBinder`, you can do something like this:

```
<g:VerticalPanel spacing="0" width="100%" height="100%" ui:field="mainPanel">
    <g:Cell horizontalAlignment="ALIGN_CENTER" verticalAlignment="ALIGN_MIDDLE">
    <!-- content goes here -->
    </g:Cell>
</g:VerticalPanel>
```

Answer (score 1):

with css? `margin:0 auto;` and `position:absolute; top:50%;` ?