# How can we centralise the myInlineHTML inside myFlowPanel (GWT) y just using 1 FlowPanel & 1 InlineHTML without using other extra Widgets?

Tags: gwt

I have just 1 FlowPanel & 1 InlineHTML, the following code doesn't make InlineHTML go into the middle of FlowPanel.

```
myFlowPanel.setWidth("100%");
myFlowPanel.add(myInlineHTML);
myInlineHTML.setHTML("<table>...</table>");
myFlowPanel.addStyleName(getView().getRes().css().textAlignCenterImportant());

//This is css
.textAlignCenterImportant{
     text-align:center !important;
}
```

**How can we centralise the myInlineHTML inside myFlowPanel (GWT) by just using 1 FlowPanel & 1 InlineHTML without using other extra widgets?**

Comment: don't use a flow panel? why insisting on using a hammer to drive screws? possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8509260/gwt-how-do-i-center-content-in-a-panel

Comment: flowpanel is very simple & Google suggest to use FlowPanel rather than VerticalpNael or HorizontalPanel cos it create quirks in old browser, Grid is not dynamic, i need dynamic. Also I need to add 1000 InlineHtml so use Flextable or any form of table will make the app really slow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This css will solve your problem. Apply it on `InlineHTML`.

```
.center_text {
    display: block;
    text-align: center !important;
}
```

`InlineHTML` in converted into `<span>` tag in HTML.

---

Here is the sample code:

```
FlowPanel fixHeaderPanel = new FlowPanel();
fixHeaderPanel.setWidth("100%");

InlineHTML inlineHTML=new InlineHTML("Hi how are you!");
inlineHTML.setStyleName("center_text");
fixHeaderPanel.add(inlineHTML);
```

Snapshot:

[image]

---

EDIT

as per your last comment.

try this one:

```
  inlineHtnl.setHTML("<table width='100%'>..</table>");
```

Comment: Can any one tell me what's the problem in this css. Please.

Comment: **Whats happening on stack overflow?** If any one down vote any answer then he/she has to provide some comments. So that he/she can at least correct his/her mistake.

Comment: i didn't vote down, but it didn't work. can u put flowpanel inside another flowpanel?

Comment: it's a whole project, but basically it like this: scrollPanel.add(flowPanel1); flowPanel1.add(flowPanel2); flowPanel2.add(inlineHtml); inlineHtnl.setHTML("<table>..</table>"); & I want the table go into the central of flowPanel2.

Comment: Try this one `inlineHtnl.setHTML("<table width='100%'>..</table>");`. The problem is with the width of `table` that you are using in `setHTML`.

Comment: Awesome, but better <table border=\"1\" align=\"center\" > then i don't need setSlyle For the GWT widget. Thank you very much for your discovery!